# jQuery show hide next previous page items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML code and I'm really struggling to come up with a solution for the following: (pseudo code, javascript or jquery answers please, but would prefer jquery)

- When the page loads, hide all of the list items except for the first
  5 (display only the first five, select by unique id)
- Two buttons on
  the bottom of the list, one for "older" one for "newer".
- When older btn is
  pressed, show the next 5 on the list (might just be one list-item if
  there is 6 altogether)
- When "newer" is pressed, show the 5 in front  of the current list-items
- Hide newer button if already on the first page 5

code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="list-item" id="13">
      <p>First Item</p>
  </div>

  <div class="list-item" id="12">
      <p>Second Item</p>
  </div>

  <div class="list-item" id="11">
    <p>Third Item</p>
  </div>

  <div class="list-item" id="10">
     <p>Fourth Item</p>
  </div>

  <div class="list-item" id="9">
     <p>Fifth Item</p>
  </div>

  <div class="list-item" id="8">
     <p>Sixth Item</p>
  </div>

   … ( more list-items)

</div>

<button onclick="showOlder()">Older</button>
<button onclick="showNewer()">Newer</button>
```

Comment: can you share whatever you have tried.?

Comment: Can I suggest a logic change here? e.g. place each 5 records in a container div and call that div "page-x" x being the number of pages. OR have 5 divs constant on the page and update its data (you are probably getting them from db of some sort right?

Comment: I never thought of that @KemalEmin . The problem is: I will always want to show the last 5 first, so if there is 13, it should show 13, 12, 11, 10, 9. however It will show only 13, 12 , 11 because that's would be page 3. Hopefully that makes sense. So it would only show the last added 5 if there is exactly 5 in the last page, for example if there were 15 items.

Answer (score 0):

After further research and trial and error I Was able to come up with a solution. I thought I'd post it if anyone else is looking for something similar. Please note I'm not an expert in jQuery and this code can probably be done in a more optimised way.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    btnNewer.hide();

    for (i = numOfItems; i >= 1; i--) {
        if (i == numOfItems - (5 * page)) {
            page++;
        }
        $("#" + i).addClass("Page-" + page);
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= numOfPages; i++) {
        if (i != 1) {
            hidePage(i);
        }
    }
});

var numOfItems = $('div.list-item').length;
var numOfPages = Math.ceil(numOfItems / 5);
var page = 1;
var currentPage = 1;
var btnOlder = $("#showOlder")
var btnNewer = $("#showNewer")



function hidePage(pageNum) {
    $('.Page-' + pageNum).hide();
}

function showPage(pageNum) {
    $('.Page-' + pageNum).show();
}


btnOlder.on("click", function () {
    hidePage(currentPage);
    currentPage++;
    showPage(currentPage);
    CheckIfOnLastPage();
    CheckIfOnFirstPage();
})

btnNewer.on("click", function () {
    hidePage(currentPage);
    currentPage--;
    showPage(currentPage);
    CheckIfOnFirstPage();
    CheckIfOnLastPage();
})

function CheckIfOnFirstPage() {
    if (currentPage == 1) {
        btnNewer.hide();
    } else {
        btnNewer.show();
    }
}

function CheckIfOnLastPage() {
    if (currentPage == numOfPages) {
        btnOlder.hide();
    } else {
        btnOlder.show();
    }
}
```